# Webpack script-loader jQuery ajaxPrefilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm using Webpack to package my project and I'm including jquery. I need to set ajaxPrefilter on the jquery instance. So any time I do `import $ from 'jquery'`, i receive an instance with a configured ajaxPrefilter.

I was thinking of using `script-loader` which would run `$.ajaxPrefilter(filterFunc)`. But I can't seem to get it working. I thought script-loader would append my custom script to the bottom of the built file. But there's nothing.

Basically, I would just like to execute whatever is in `jquery.conf.js` if anything imports `jquery`.
Or if anyone knows, how does the script-loader actually work? I can't seem to understand

Here's my webpack configuration

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/entry',
  entry: {
    index1: './index1',
    index2: './index2',
  },
  output: {
    path: './build',
    filename: '[name].entry.chunk.js'
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules']
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', 'json'],
    alias: {
      'actions': __dirname+'/actions',
      'dialogs': __dirname+'/dialogs',
      'gettext': __dirname+'/utils/gettext.js',
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js$/, loaders: ['babel', 'eslint-loader'], exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: require.resolve("react"), loader: "expose?React" },
      { test: require.resolve("moment-timezone"), loader: "expose?moment" },
      { test: require.resolve("immutable"), loader: "expose?Immutable" },
      { include: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" },
      { test: require.resolve("jquery"), loader: "script-loader?"+__dirname+"/jquery.conf.js" }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('commons.chunk.js'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "$": "jquery",
      "jQuery": "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
    }),
  ],
  eslint: {
    failOnError: true,
    failOnWarning: false,
  }
};
```

And my `jquery.conf.js` is basically

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr){
  /* my filter function */
});
```

Any help appreciated!